# tokuDb setting for time to timesout a statement

Tags: mariadb, tokudb

In a mariadb table with tokuDb engine; I am ecountering the below error - either on a delete statement; whilst there is a background insert load, and vice versa.

`Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`

Does tokuDb user a setting that can be updated to determine how long it waits before it timesout a statement?

I couldn't find the answer in tokuDb documents. The maria varaible is still at its default value: 'lock_wait_timeout', '31536000' -- but my timeout is coming back in quite a bit less than a year. The timeouts are coming during a load test; and I haven't spotted a time value in the error - but it feels like a few seconds; to minutes at the most before the timeout is thrown.

Thanks,
Brent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TokuDB has its own [timeout variable](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/tokudb-system-variables/#tokudb_lock_timeout), `tokudb_lock_timeout`, it is measured in milliseconds and has the default value `4000` (4 seconds), which fits your observations. It can be modified both on the session and global levels, and can also be configured in the .cnf file.

Remember that when you set a global value for a variable which has both scopes, it only affects future sessions (connections), but not the existing ones.

```
-- for the current session
SET SESSION tokudb_lock_timeout = 60000;

-- for future sessions
SET GLOBAL tokudb_lock_timeout = 60000;
```

Comment: Before raising it, think seriously about what the long-running query is doing.  It currently says that it is OK to stall a user for up to 4 seconds.  Maybe the long-running query can be rewritten?